# Regular Expression to deal with text issue

Tags: regex

I have the following text sample:

```
Sample Supplier 123

 AP Invoices    123456  -229.00
 AP Invoices    235435  337.00  
 AP Invoices    444323  228.00  
 AP Invoices    576432  248.00
```

It's from a text file with 21,000 lines, which lists invoices against a supplier.

The pattern is always the same on each block of invoices against each supplier, where:

1. The supplier name starts at the beginning of a line
2. The invoices being to be listed 2 rows down from the supplier name, indented by one space.

I wondered if I can use a Regular Expression (I'm using TextPad as a Text Editor on a Windows PC) to:

1. Append each invoice line with a tab (\t)
2. Append the supplier name in front of the tab so each invoice line now starts with the supplier name, and a tab, where the supplier name is taken from 2 rows above the start of each block of invoices
3. Delete the supplier name line from above the invoice block.

Expected output:

```
Sample Supplier 123  AP Invoices    123456  -229.00
Sample Supplier 123  AP Invoices    235435  337.00  
Sample Supplier 123  AP Invoices    444323  228.00  
Sample Supplier 123  AP Invoices    576432  248.00
```

I realise I am probably asking for "the moon on a stick" here, but the alternative is to go through a 21,000 line text file and copy and paste the data into Excel, which might not be a very good use of my time.

Maybe I can't do it using a simple regular expression, or maybe it's simply not possible at all.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple Python script to solve this issue:

```
currentheader = ""
with open("yourfile.txt") as f:
    with open("newfile.txt","w") as fw:
        for line in f:
            if len(line.strip()) == 0:
                continue
            elif line[0] != " ": #new header
                currentheader = line[:-1]
            else:
                fw.write(currentheader + "\t" + line[1:])
```

For this to work, on Windows you will have to [install Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/). Python 2 or 3 should both work with this script. After installing Python, you open a command line (`Win+R`, `cmd`, `Enter`), navigate to the folder your file is in using `cd foldername`, if necessary, and then type `python dealWithTextIssue.py` (after having saved the script as "dealWithTextIssue.py" there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this isn't solvable just with regex, you'll have to do some programming. I made a little script in PHP:

```
$string = <<<EOL
Sample Supplier 123

 AP Invoices    123456  -229.00
 AP Invoices    235435  337.00  
 AP Invoices    444323  228.00  
 AP Invoices    576432  248.00 

Second Supplier
 A B    C D
 B    F
EOL;

$array = preg_split("~[\n\r]+~", $string);

foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (strpos($value, " ") == 0) {
        if (strlen(trim($value)) > 0) {
            echo "\t".$header.rtrim($value).PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    else {
        $header = $value;
    }
}
```

You can see it at work for example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c84142e18929b29bfac490b214e8ee159e7fcf3f) after clicking on execute code.